# properly format string of emails using python

Tags: python-3.x, mime

I have a piece of code that extracts the email addresses from a list and adds them to the 'To' field in the MIME service. Only the very first recipient gets the email due to a misconstrued email list.

The 'list.csv' file looks like this

```
john.doe@domain.com
jean.donna@domain.com
```

The code I'm using to format the addresses is this:

```
with open('list.csv') as allusers:
        concat_out =', '.join(email for (email,) in csv.reader(allusers))
receiver = [concat_out]
```

MIME part:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Notification'
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = '; '.join(receiver)
```

Output:

```
['john.doe@domain.com, jean.donna@domain.com'] #notice the missing quotes and a comma
                                               #instead of a semi-colon
```

How can I get the list properly formatted to look like this?:

```
['john.doe@domain.com', 'jean.donna@domain.com']
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your issue without touching the old code

```
with open('list.csv') as allusers:
        concat_out =', '.join(email for (email,) in csv.reader(allusers))
reciever=concat_out.split(',')
print(reciever)
```

> output: ['john.doe@domain.com', ' jean.donna@domain.com']

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a list and then make a string from the list.

```py
with open('list.csv') as allusers:
        concat_out = [email for (email,) in csv.reader(allusers)]
receiver = str(concat_out)
```

This will give you an output like:

```
"['john.doe@domain.com', 'jean.donna@domain.com'] "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
email_list = []
with open('list.csv', 'r') as file:
   for line in file.readlines():
       email_list.append(line.strip('\n'))

print(email_list)
```

Output:
['john.doe@domain.com', 'jean.donna@domain.com']